# Hide UITableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to Hide a cell from a UITableView. just like the delete action do but i just want to hide it to later show it in the same position.

i know that UITableViewCell has a property called "Hidden" but when i hide the Cell using this property it hide but no animated and they leave a blank space

Example:

1. first cell
2. second cell
3. third cell

it's possible that when i hide the second cell,  that third cell change position to 2 ?

thanks

Comment: You can add cell at particular position, same like you delete., have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503958/how-to-add-item-to-uitableview

Comment: You need to remove the cell and later insert the cell.

Comment: UITableView has insert/delete cell methods with animation option but you must manage your data source by yourself while you use these methods.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Comment: I think you are looking for this.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28020367/3411787

Comment: The `hidden` property you mention is actually on `UIView`, so you can hide any view. This however simply makes it invisible, it doesn't update `UITableView`'s accounting for the row height.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way to effectively "hide" a row with animation and without actually removing it is to set it's height to zero. You'd do so by overriding `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0;
    if (isRowHidden) {
        height = 0.0;
    } else {
        height = 44.0;
    }
    return height;
}
```

(You'd only want to return 0.0 for the specific row or rows you want to hide of course, not unconditionally).

Simply changing the return value of this method doesn't make the table view automatically adjust the row's height, to make it do so you make the following calls.

```
isRowHidden = YES;
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

If you do so you'll see an animated appearance/disappearance transition between the two.

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted. This will hide all rows (or none).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to imply that you wouldn't do it for *all* rows in the table view, just the one you meant to show/hide. I should've made that clearer. Will update.

Comment: You only want a zero height for a specific row (or rows). As written, you return a zero height for all or no rows.

Comment: As written it's only for rows where `isRowHidden` evaluates to `YES`, I've left the details of that up to the reader.

Comment: As written you leave `isRowHidden` to `YES` so initially all visible rows get reloaded with a zero height which mean all rows from the current top row to the end of the table become invisible. Then as the user scrolls up, the remaining rows get a zero height too. Leaving out the important details makes the answer fairly useless. A good answer would show how to solve the problem properly.

Comment: I updated the answer with this clarifying comment - "(You'd only want to return 0.0 for the specific row or rows you want to hide of course, not unconditionally)." Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: To make the answer more understandable, just change isRowHidden to isRowHidden[indexPath.row]. This way, the row appears/hidden based on the array of boolean defined/setup by coder.

Answer (score 22):

In **SWIFT** you need to do two things,

1. **HIDE** your cell.    (because reusable cell may conflict)
2. Set Height of cell to **ZERO**.

Look at here,

1. **HIDE** cell

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
                  cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

      if indexPath.row == 1 {
          cell?.hidden = true
      } else {
          cell?.hidden = false
      }
      return cell      
   }
   ```
2. Set Height of cell to **ZERO**.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

       var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0

       if(indexPath.row == 1){
           rowHeight = 0.0
       } else {
           rowHeight = 55.0    //or whatever you like
       }
       return rowHeight
   }
   ```

Using this you can remove reusable cell conflict issues.

You can do the same for **cell?.tag** also to hide specific cell by tag.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020367/3411787

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Answers should be in the appropriate language.

Comment: Right but as an iOS developer changing code between these two is not a big problem.

Comment: Hiding `UITableViewCell`s and setting their height manually is a bad idea because they're managed and recycled by their parent `UITableView`. If you change the properties of a cell like hiding it it will remain hidden when recycled by its `UITableView`.

Comment: @TimJohnsen , please implement what you said, and then try scrolling your tableview, you will know the fact.

Comment: You still shouldn't be hiding table view cells.

Comment: I tried adding "cell.isSelected = true" to cellForRowAt


Then follow by func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 50
    }
}

Not working, any reason why not? Shouldn't the rows are now "selected" so it will have a height of 0?

Answer (score 8):

If you want the other cells to have a dynamic height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 1 { // Or any other row
            return 0
        }
        return -1.0
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Been looking for this answer

Answer (score 7):

You can't simply hide a UITableViewCell. You have to remove that cell from the table view then insert it again when you would like it to reappear in the table.

The methods you're looking for are `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. These are well documented in the UITableView documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/). You're going to have to remember where you removed the cell from then insert it at the same position later.

Keep in mind that if you add cells to your table with a lesser row index than the row index of the deleted row, you will have to add on to the index to maintain it's relative position.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Same as [Zaid Pathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3411787/zaid-pathan) but for Swift 4:

```
    //HIDE you cell.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    //hide second cell
    indexPath.row == 1 ? (cell.isHidden = true): (cell.isHidden = false)

    return myCell       
}


//Set Height of cell to ZERO.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
    indexPath.row == 1 ? (rowHeight = 0.0): (rowHeight = 49.0)
return rowHeight
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `cell.isHidden = indexPath.row == 1`?

Comment: You're correct. Your proposed option is indeed more concise and simplified. I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Hidden in Attributes Inspector of TableViewCell -> ContentView and then implement method:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if shouldHideSection(indexPath.section) {
        return 0.0
    } else if let isHidden = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.contentView.isHidden, isHidden {
        return 0.0
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: I like the solution but I seem to be getting an overflow error when calling cellForRow

Answer (score 0):

You should delete row and reload table view
[tbv reloadData];

Comment: Important to note that this will hide or show the row *without* animation.

Answer (score 0):

cell display, depending on the data source, so you need to deal with the data source.

if dataArr is the table view datasource,first of all, you should delete the data source where the cell,then

```
[dataArr removeObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

at last ,you can insert data source when you should add a cell

```
[dataArr insertObjectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexpath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to set rowHeight value in condition check

Dataarray where value stored .

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //set up here
    
     let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)  as! myCustomCell
    
    
    if (dataArray?[indexPath.row].somevalue == "true")
    {
        cell.isHidden = true
        tableview.rowHeight = 0.0
      
    }
    else{
    // show cell values 
     tableview.rowHeight = 130
```

}
`

Answer (score -3):

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

             let dicttemp : Dictionary = arrAllCoursesList[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String,Any>

             var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0

             if let getStatus = dicttemp["status"] as? String
             {
                if getStatus == "1"
                {
                    rowHeight = 240.0
                }
                else
                {
                     rowHeight = 0.0
                }
             }

            return rowHeight

        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

             let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CompetitionTableViewCell") as! CompetitionTableViewCell

            let dicttemp : Dictionary = arrAllCoursesList[indexPath.row] as! Dictionary<String,Any>

  if let getStatus = dicttemp["status"] as? String
            {
                if getStatus == "1"
                {
                    cell.isHidden = false
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.isHidden = true
                }
            }


            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            return cell

        }
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21593298)