# Display only similar compared data into table view

Tags: arrays, swift, compare, tableview

I have question which is little bit similar as my previous, but different.

There is a code description:
I have 2 Json arrays which I try to compare in my code -> all and allUrl. When array all contains some id from array allUrl image table row should be change to red, or vice versa green.

And my new question:How can I display only "red_icon" data in table?This data should be similar for this two arrays.thanks

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

cell.textLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].id
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].timestampValue

let listOfStudentsUrl = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.timestampValue}
           // Compare data

        listOfStudentsUrl.forEach{ key in print(key)    

        if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
        break
        }else{
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"green_icon")
    }}
        return cell
    }
```

Correct working code after discussion below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell



let listOfStudentsUrl = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.timestampValue}
           // Compare data

        listOfStudentsUrl.forEach{ key in print(key)    

        if  all[indexPath.row].id == key.key {
        cell.textLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].id
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = all[indexPath.row].timestampValue
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"red_icon")
        cell.isHidden = false
        break
        }else{
        cell.isHidden = true
    }}
        return cell
    }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

      var rowHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
    let listOfStudentsUrl = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.timestampValue}

           for key in listOfStudentsUrl{
            if all[indexPath.row].id == key.key{
                rowHeight = 49.0
                break
            }else{
                rowHeight = 0.0
    }}
  return rowHeight
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are trying to hide some specific cells of your TableView. 
One way you could do this is hiding your cell and then setting it's height to zero.

To hide it, use  the  property `.isHidden`.
To change it's height, override the function `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

See this for more: [Hide UITableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886642/hide-uitableview-cell)

Comment: Yeees it's working!  :)  It was height row!
thank you @Maria